# Why can't I set the width on my plotly bar chart?

Tags: python, plotly

No matter what I try...I cannot seem to adjust the width of my plotly bar chart. Here is my current code and output:

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(
    x=top_10_belg['ID'],
    y=top_10_belg['Description'],
    marker=dict(color='rgba(50, 171, 96, 0.6)',
                line=dict(color='rgba(50, 171, 96, 1.0)',width=1))
    ,orientation='h'))

fig.update_layout(
    title='Top 10 Rule Breaks by ID',
    height = 500, width = 400,
    yaxis=dict(
        showgrid=False,
        showline=False,
        showticklabels=True
        ),
xaxis=dict(
        zeroline=False,
        showline=False,
        showticklabels=True,
        showgrid=False,
    ),barmode='group', bargap=0.4,bargroupgap=0.0,
paper_bgcolor='white',
    plot_bgcolor='white')

fig.update_yaxes(ticksuffix = "  ")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")

fig.show()
```

I had to line out the labels due to confidentiality.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of the bar chart is set by the number of bars in the list. The value 1.0 sets the interval to zero. So as an example, the width 0.8 is used to list for the category variable. I have reproduced the similar horizontal bar chart in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-bar-charts/#bar-chart-with-line-plot) using your decorations.

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(
    x=top_10_belg['ID'],
    y=top_10_belg['Description'],
    width=[0.8]*len(top_10_belg['Description']), # update
    marker=dict(color='rgba(50, 171, 96, 0.6)',
                line=dict(color='rgba(50, 171, 96, 1.0)',
                          width=1)),
    orientation='h'))
```

[image]

Since increasing the x-axis is the same as increasing the width of the graph size, the width of the x-axis can be increased by adding the following code.

```
fig.update_layout(autosize=True, width=1000)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I may have misspoken. I would like my x axis to be wider, and by this I mean the overall width of the chart. The bars do not stretch further out across the x axis no matter what I try.

Comment: Added an example with a larger graph width. Values are in pixels.